# Solve the Partial Differential Equation $z^2(p^2 z^2+q^2)=1$ where $p=\frac{\partial z }{\partial x}$ and $q=\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}$.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

I used Charpit formula but the problem became bigger and bigger. Is there any substitution which reduces the problem to a simpler form?

Comment: The PDE can be simplified with the change of function $z^2=Z$ leading to $$Z\,P^2+Q^2=4$$ $P=\frac{\partial Z}{\partial x}$ and $Q=\frac{\partial Z}{\partial y}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't expect the general solution which would involve some arbitrary function. Since this isn't a first order linear PDE be satisfied if you find at least some particular solutions thanks to the Charpit relationships.
$$\Phi(x,y,z,p,q)=z^4p^2+z^2q^2-1$$
$$\Phi_x=\Phi_y=0\quad;\quad \Phi_z=4z^3p^2+2zq^2\quad;\quad \Phi_p=2z^4p\quad;\quad \Phi_q=2z^2q$$
$$\frac{dx}{\Phi_p}= \frac{dy}{\Phi_q}=\frac{dz}{p\Phi_p+q\Phi_q}=\frac{dp}{-p\Phi_x-p\Phi_z}=\frac{dq}{-\Phi_y-q\Phi_z}$$
$$\frac{dx}{2z^4p}= \frac{dy}{2z^2q}=\frac{dz}{2z^4p^2+2z^2q^2}=\frac{dp}{-p(4z^3p^2+2zq^2)}=\frac{dq}{-q(4z^3p^2+2zq^2)}$$
$$\frac{dp}{-p(4z^3p^2+2zq^2)}=\frac{dq}{-q(4z^3p^2+2zq^2)}\quad\implies\quad \frac{dp}{p}=\frac{dq}{q}$$
$$p=cq=\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}=c\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}\quad ;\quad c=\text{constant}$$
Solving $\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}=c\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}$ leads to $z=f(y+cx)$. One expect to find some solutions on the form :
$$z=f(y+cx)\quad;\quad p=cf'\quad;\quad q=f'\quad\text{meaning}\quad f'=\frac{df(X)}{dX}\quad\text{with}\quad X=y+c\,x$$
$f$ is a function to be determined to satisfy the PDE.
$$z^4p^2+z^2q^2=1=f^4c^2f'^2+f^2f'^2$$
Let $\quad F=f^2$
$$1=f^4c^2f'^2+f^2f'^2=f^2f'^2(c^2f^2+1)=\left(\frac{F'}{2}\right)^2(c^2F+1)$$
$$\sqrt{c^2F+1}\:F'=2$$
Integrating leads to :
$$\frac{2}{3c^2}(c^2F(X)+1)^{3/2}=2(X+C)\quad;\quad X=y+cx$$
$C=$ constant.
$$F(X)=\frac{1}{c^2}\left(3c^2(X+C)\right)^{2/3}-\frac{1}{c^2}$$
$$f(X)=\pm\frac{1}{c} \sqrt{\left(3c^2(X+C)\right)^{2/3}-1}$$
$$\boxed{z(x,y)=\pm\frac{1}{c} \sqrt{\Big(3c^2(y+c\,x+C)\Big)^{2/3}-1}}$$
This is a family of solutions of the PDE with two arbitrary constants.